# How could I get (print) all inner html from node which I select using python's lxml etree and xpath?

Tags: python, xpath, html-parsing, lxml, xml.etree

How could I get all inner html from node which I select using etree xpath:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> doc = '<foo><bar><div>привет привет</div></bar></foo>'
>>> hparser = etree.HTMLParser()
>>> htree = etree.parse(StringIO(doc), hparser)
>>> foo_element = htree.xpath("//foo")
```

How could I now print all foo_element's inner HTML as text? I need to get this:

```
<bar><div>привет привет</div></bar>
```

---

BTW when I tried to use `lxml.html.tostring` I get strange output:

```
>>> import lxml.etree
>>> lxml.html.tostring(foo_element[0])
'<foo><bar><div>&#208;&#191;&#209;&#128;&#208;&#184;&#208;&#178;&#208;&#181;&#209;&#130; &#208;&#191;&#209;&#128;&#208;&#178;&#208;&#184;&#208;&#181;&#209;&#130;</div></bar></foo>'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the same technique as shown in [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3446055/2998271). Example in the context of this question :

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> from lxml import html
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> doc = '<foo><bar><div>TEST NODE</div></bar></foo>'
>>> hparser = etree.HTMLParser()
>>> htree = etree.parse(StringIO(doc), hparser)
>>> foo_element = htree.xpath("//foo")
>>> print ''.join(html.tostring(e) for e in foo_element[0])
<bar><div>TEST NODE</div></bar>
```

Or to handle case when the element may contain text node child :

```
>>> doc = '<foo>text node child<bar><div>TEST NODE</div></bar></foo>'
>>> htree = etree.parse(StringIO(doc), hparser)
>>> foo_element = htree.xpath("//foo")
>>> print foo_element[0].text + ''.join(html.tostring(e) for e in foo_element[0])
text node child<bar><div>TEST NODE</div></bar>
```

Refactoring the code into a separate function as shown in the linked post is strongly advised for the real case.

Comment: Thanks. This solution gives  unreadable output for non-latin characters `'<foo><bar><div>&#208;&#191;&#209;&#128;&#208;&#184;&#208;&#178;&#208;&#181;&#209;&#130; &#208;&#191;&#209;&#128;&#208;&#178;&#208;&#184;&#208;&#181;&#209;&#130;</div></bar></foo>'` Is there a way to make it human-readable?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help on that part, as I can't even assign such non-latin characters to my `doc` variable in IDLE (got "*Unsupported characters in input*" error message). And judging from the question title, that should go in separate question I think. That's an entirely different problem.