# Xpath extract current node content including all child node

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I've met a problem while extracting current node content including all child node.

Just like the following code, I want to get string 
`abcdefg<b>b1b2b3</b>`
in pre tag.

But I could not use "child::*" to get it.
If I use "/text()", I lost b tag format information. Please help me out.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from lxml import html
import lxml.etree as le

input = "<pre>abcdefg<b>b1b2b3</b></pre>"
input_xpath = "//pre/child::*"
tree = html.fromstring(input)
result = tree.xpath(input_xpath)
result1 = [le.tostring(item) for item in result]
result2 = ''.join(result1)
print result2

output: <b>b1b2b3</b>
```

Comment: It's difficult for me. I don't know how to solve you question by lxml.

Comment: @TonyYang fyi, check the answer below and the linked question for possible options to solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get XML node's content markup (sometimes referred to as ["innerXML"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443831/python-and-elementtree-return-inner-xml-excluding-parent-element)) , you can start by selecting the node (instead of selecting the child or the text content) :

```
from lxml import html
import lxml.etree as le

input = "<pre>abcdefg<b>b1b2b3</b></pre>"
tree = html.fromstring(input)
node = tree.xpath("//pre")[0]
```

then combine the text content with all child nodes markup :

```
result = node.text + ''.join(le.tostring(e) for e in node)
print result
```

Output :

```
abcdefg<b>b1b2b3</b>
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good answer. If the input  is "<pre><b>b1b2b3</b>abcdefg</pre>" of string, what would you do?

Comment: Would you use `result = ''.join(le.tostring(e) for e in node) + node.text` to answer me?

Comment: @TonyYang Surprisingly, the code almost work for that case too. The only problem in that case was `node.Text` return `None` so it can't be combined with a string. Adding `None` checking yield the expected result for me: `node.text if node.text else '' + ''.join(le.tostring(e) for e in node)`

Answer (score 0):

try replacing your xpath with the following

```
In [0]: input = "<pre>abcdefg<b>b1b2b3</b></pre>"

In [1]: input_xpath = "//pre//text()"

In [2]: tree = html.fromstring(input)

In [3]: result = tree.xpath(input_xpath)

In [4]: result
Out[5]: ['abcdefg', 'b1b2b3']
```

Comment: actually this is not what I want. Because b1b2b3 lost <b> tag information