# Getting value from XML file in Python

Tags: python, xml

Let's consider a sample XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<feats>
  <feat>
    <name>Blindsight, 5-Ft. Radius</name>
    <type>General</type>
    <multiple>No</multiple>
    <stack>No</stack>
    <prerequisite>Base attack bonus +4, Blind-Fight, Wisdom 19.</prerequisite>
    <benefit><div topic="Benefit" level="8"><p><b>Benefit:</b> Using senses such as acute hearing and sensitivity to vibrations, you detect the location of opponents who are no more than 5 feet away from you. <i>Invisibility</i> and <i>darkness</i> are irrelevant, though it you discern incorporeal beings.</p><p/>
</div>
</benefit>
    <full_text>
      <div topic="Blindsight, 5-Ft. Radius" level="3">Lorem ipsum
</div>
</div>
    </full_text>
    <reference>SRD 3.5 DivineAbilitiesandFeats</reference>
  </feat>
</feats>
```

I want to get a text from `<benefit>` tag as a string but without a `<div>` tag( `<p>` and `<b>` should not be deleted). So in this case the result will be:

```
Using senses such as acute hearing and sensitivity to vibrations, you detect the location of opponents who are no more than 5 feet away from you. <i>Invisibility</i> and <i>darkness</i> are irrelevant, though it you discern incorporeal beings.</p><p/>
```

I managed to get the whole `<div>` element but when I try to get a string from it using `.text` property it gives mo `None`.

```
tree = ET.parse(filename)
root = tree.getroot()
data={}
for item in root.findall('feat'):
    data["benefit"]=""

    element = item.find('benefit').find("div")
    print element.text
```

Is there a simple metod to get just this text or I have to write special function for it?

Comment: have you checked out [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with mattR about BeautifulSoup, However

**I added some regular expressions to your snippet and it gives me a nice result**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re
tree = ET.parse('data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
data = {};
result = [];
for item in root.iter('benefit'):

    cleaned = re.sub(r'<[^>]*>', '', ET.tostring(item, encoding="utf-8"));
    result.append(cleaned)

print result;
//result ['Benefit: Using senses such as acute hearing and sensitivity to vibrations, you detect the location of opponents who are no more than 5 feet away from you. Invisibility and darkness are irrelevant, though it you discern incorporeal beings.\n\n\n    ']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `lxml` you can find the `<b>` element first, get the `tail` and combine it with following-sibling elements to produce the desired result, for example :

```
from lxml import etree as ET
raw = '''your XML string here'''

root = ET.fromstring(raw)
b = root.xpath("//benefit/div/p/b")[0]
result = b.tail + ''.join(ET.tostring(node) for node in b.xpath("following-sibling::*"))
print result
```

**output :**

```
  Using senses such as acute hearing and sensitivity to vibrations, you detect the location of opponents who are no more than 5 feet away from you. <i>Invisibility</i> and <i>darkness</i> are irrelevant, though it you discern incorporeal beings.
```

Or if you mean to simply get the content of `<p>` entirely, including the tags within, you can do [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29888556/2998271) (this one works using either `lxml` or `xml.etree` :

```
p = root.find(".//benefit/div/p")
result = p.text + ''.join(ET.tostring(node) for node in p)
```

**output :**

```
<b>Benefit:</b> Using senses such as acute hearing and sensitivity to vibrations, you detect the location of opponents who are no more than 5 feet away from you. <i>Invisibility</i> and <i>darkness</i> are irrelevant, though it you discern incorporeal beings.
```