# If there are multiple possible return values, should pyright automatically infer the right one, based on the passed arguments?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, type-hinting, python-typing, pylance

I have the following function:

```
from lxml import etree
from typing import Union


def _get_inner_xml(element: Union[etree._Element, None]) -> Union[str, None]:
    if element is None:
        return None
        
    # See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51124963
    return (str(element.text or "") + "".join(etree.tostring(child, encoding="unicode") for child in element)).strip()


root = etree.fromstring('<html><body>TEXT<br/>TAIL</body></html>')
innerXML = _get_inner_xml(root)
print(innerXML)
```

My understanding of it is that if I pass `None` as an argument, I always get `None` as a return value. On the other hand, an `etree._Element` as argument will always result in a `str` return.

If I write the following in vscode using pylance (it uses pyright under the hood):

```
def test(element: etree._Element):
    variable = _get_inner_xml(element)
```

In this case I get the type hint `(variable) variable: str | None`. I would expect pylance to know that variable should be of the type `str`. Am I overseeing something? Is this maybe a bug?

If this works as intended: Is there a possibility to manually tell pylance that "whenever this function gets a `etree._Element` it will return a `str` and whenever I pass `None` it returns `None`"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer here is to use `typing.overload` (documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload)), which allows you to register multiple different signatures for one function. Function definitions decorated with `@overload` are ignored at runtime — they are just for the type-checker — so the body of the function can be filled with a literal ellipsis `...`, `pass`, or just a docstring. You also need to make sure you provide a "concrete" implementation of the function that doesn't use `@overload`.

```
from lxml import etree
from typing import Union, overload

@overload
def _get_inner_xml(element: etree._Element) -> str: 
    """Signature when `element` is of type `etree._Element`"""

@overload
def _get_inner_xml(element: None) -> None: ...
    """Signature when `element` is of type `None`"""

def _get_inner_xml(element: Union[etree._Element, None]) -> Union[str, None]:
    if element is None:
        return None
        
    # See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51124963
    return (str(element.text or "") + "".join(etree.tostring(child, encoding="unicode") for child in element)).strip()


root = etree.fromstring('<html><body>TEXT<br/>TAIL</body></html>')
innerXML = _get_inner_xml(root)
print(innerXML)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is great!

Comment: No worries, glad I could help!

Comment: Official documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload for future reference

Answer (score 0):

This is not how type hinting works. To know that an input of `etree._Element` always results in a return of `etree._Element` and an input of `None` always results in `None` the IDE would need to parse the function, analyse all paths and get to that result.

I highly doubt that it is build to do that. Instead the IDE simply parses  for annotations in the signatures and returns them as hint - type hints are just that - they are not enforced on code execution.

You may want to check with a simpler function:

```
# this will either return a None or a str - it simply returns what is inputted
def test(element: Union[str, None]) -> Union[str, None]:
    return element


should_be_str = test("should be a str as type hint return")
should_be_none = test(None) 

should_be_marked_as_type_mismatch = test(42) # works from the signature information
```

and see if your IDE picks that one up - I seriously doubt it.

Comment: You are right, I get the same behavior with the function you sent. What is the best way to work with such a function in typed code? Explicitly cast the return value every time the function is called?

Comment: This answer is correct, but could be more constructive, given that the problem is easily solved with `typing.overload`

Comment: @Alex thanks for pointing me to \@overload, did not encounter that one yet - good way to solve this.